# What are scorestreaks in multiplayer of Black Ops 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

First time playing online fps before, so I've no idea what I'm doing. But I'm getting a hang of it. But I was wondering what scorestreaks are. I know you need points for that, but where exactly can I see my points? 
And I tried selecting 3 random scorestreaks but I don't know how to use it in-game!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After choosing your kill-streaks, you need to get in-game points by getting kills, assists, or scoring objectives.
You can see your progress on the right hand-side of your HUD, there is a meter that shows you how much points you have earned in this life.  When you get enough points for your first kill-streak you will be able to activate it by pressing the right directional pad (on PS3 or Xbox). If you collect your second and third kill-streaks, you can choose which to activate with up and down and the directional pad.

PS- when you die, the meter will start over again from beginning. Hope this helped :)

Comment: I use XBox 360. I dont see any meter. but i see a number next to my name.

Answer (score 0):

In Black Ops 2 multiplayer Killstreaks have been replaced with Scorestreaks, which are earned by killing enemies, assisting teammates and completing different objectives. For example, a normal kill gets you 100 points, but capturing a flag gives you 200 points - you will also get points when your teammates kill enemies while your UAV is active.

The UAV, for example, can be called in at 350 points, but you will need 1600 points to call in the powerful VTOL Warship. You can equip a maximum of 3 Scorestreak rewards at the same time.

Your Scorestreak resets to zero once you die. The equipped Scorestreak rewards in BO2 can be earned multiple times in one life, but they need to be used before the Scorestreak loops around for the second time or each Scorestreak reward is replaced / wasted with the same reward again.

Using the perk Hardline, the score towards the player's scorestreak is increased by 25% meaning this perk is extremely beneficial for obtaining the higher rewards. For example, if one was trying to receive a Swarm and was using Hardline, he would only require a 1585 scorestreak rather than 1900. This equates to 3 fewer kills in Team Deathmatch.

The Player's Scorestreak rewards can be obtained multiple times in one life, but only if the player uses his/her scorestreak prior to receiving the same scorestreak again. For example, if the player earns the Swarm scorestreak, chooses to save it, and they earn the Swarm again, the first Swarm will be lost, being replaced by the second Swarm received by the player.

**UAV - 350 Points**

UAV
Shows enemies on the radar as red dots for 30 seconds. The UAV can be shot down by the enemy.

**RC-XD - 450 Points**

RC-XD
Allows you to remote control a small car that's packed with explosives. The RC-XD can be detonated at will - enemies can also shoot to destroy it.

**Hunter Killer - 525 Points**

Hunter Killer
Deploys a flying drone that seeks out and tries to destroy the nearest enemy player or vehicle.

**Care Package - 550 Points**

Care Package
The Care Package is the same as in previous Call of Duty games: it gives you a random scorestreak / killstreak. The Care Package can be hacked by the enemy team.

**Counter-UAV - 600 Points**

Counter-UAV
Temporarily disables the enemy radar for 30 seconds - the Counter-UAV drone can be shot down by the enemy.

**Guardian - 650 Points**

Guardian
After the Guardian dish is deployed, it projects a microwave field that stuns enemies by slowing them down and also making their vision blurry.

**Hellstorm Missile - 700 Points**

Hellstorm Missile
The Hellstorm Missile works like the Predator Missile from the Modern Warfare series; it allows you to remotely control one missile to the ground. The missile can be scattered into a cluster bomb at will.

**Lightning Strike - 750 Points**

Lightning Strike
Equivalent to the Mortar Team killstreak from Call of Duty: Black Ops. You can choose three locations on the map for a coordinated strike.

**Sentry Gun - 800 Points**

Sentry Gun
An advanced version of the normal Sentry Gun that's been featured in previous Call of Duty games; once deployed, the Sentry Gun automatically attacks enemies. This version can, however, be remote-controlled at anytime.

**Death Machine - 850 Points**

Death Machine
Gives you a powerful minigun that can take out enemies with a couple of hits. Unlike in Black Ops, the Death Machine lasts until it runs out of ammo, even after dying - the Scorestreak can be reactivated and the ammo count is where you left off. All killstreak weapons work the same way on the Xbox 360, PlayStation 3, Wii U and PC versions.

**War Machine - 900 Points**

War Machine
The War Machine is a semi-automatic grenade launcher with a 6 round magazine. The War Machine works like the Death Machine; it lasts until all the grenades have been used.

**Dragonfire - 975 Points**

Dragonfire
Allows you to remote-control a quadrotor droid that's equipped with a lightweight machine gun. The Dragonfire is lightly armored, so it can be shot down by the enemy with ease.

**AGR - 1000 Points**

AGR
The AGR (autonomous ground robot) is air-dropped into the battlefield and it automatically attacks enemies - it can also be remote-controlled at anytime. The AGR is heavily armored and has a powerful machine gun and a rocket launcher.

**Stealth Chopper - 1100 Points**

Stealth Chopper
An advanced version of the normal Attack Helicopter from previous Call of Duty games. The Stealth Chopper circles around the map and hunts for enemies, but it doesn't appear on the enemy radar.

**Orbital VSAT - 1200 Points**

Orbital VSAT
Shows enemies on the radar, but also the direction they are facing - it shows the enemies on the radar in real time. The Orbital VSAT can't be shot down.

**Escort Drone - 1250 Points**

Escort Drone
The Escort Drone follows you around and will attempt to kill any enemies you encounter. This scorestreak reward is equivalent to the AH-6 Overwatch pointstreak from MW3, but it's more advanced.

**EMP Systems - 1300 Points**

EMP Systems
Temporarily disables enemy electronics, e.g. enemy players will have no HUD (head-up display) and can't call in Scorestreak rewards. A similar killstreak included in the Ghosts Killstreaks and Strike Packages is called the Ground Jammer.

**Warthog - 1400 Points**

Warthog
Calls in an A-10 Thunderbolt that provides air support by doing several strafe runs on the map.

**Lodestar - 1500 Points**

Lodestar
Equivalent to the Modern Warfare 3 Reaper Pointstreak; it allows you to launch multiple missiles from the Lodestar to the ground.

**VTOL Warship - 1600 Points**

VTOL Warship
Allows you to be the gunner of a powerful VTOL Warship. It works exactly like the Chopper Gunner killstreak from Call of Duty: Black Ops.

**K9 Unit - 1700 Points**

K9 Unit
Spawns multiple attack dogs that hunt down enemy players.

**Swarm - 1900 Points**

Swarm
Calls in a swarm of Hunter Killer drones that search and destroy enemies on the map.

Hope this helps

- Sources:

http://www.blackopsii.com/bo2/score-streaks-killstreaks/

http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Scorestreak

http://black-ops-2.blogspot.nl/p/killstreaks.html

Comment: This looks like it's copy-pasted from a wiki, such as http://www.blackopsii.com/bo2/score-streaks-killstreaks/. Can you link the source please?

Comment: The score streak info is a copy-paste yes but i dont see how that matters. It provides the information and i still explain everything on top.

Comment: it is considered good form to both a) copy linked information to here (for ease of reading, and in case the source goes down), and b) attribute your sources (common decency)

Answer (score 0):

These streaks (called Killstreaks) are rewards for good gameplay.
Good gameplay in this case means that you kill your enemies without dying. These killstreaks / scorestreaks need a different amount of killed enemies without dying. Note that a kill caused by a killstreak reward (Dogs, Napalm, RC-CAR, etc.) will not be counted as a normal kill for your killstreak counter.

**List of Killstreaks and their explanations:**

[List of killstreaks in Black Ops 1](http://www.codblackopsblog.com/call-of-duty-black-ops-killstreak-rewards-list/)

[List of killstreaks in Black Ops 2](http://www.blackopsii.com/bo2/score-streaks-killstreaks/)

**How to use and get Sillstreaks / scorestreaks:**

[Here is a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVJGgdgKlUQ) for an example video how you use your killstreaks and how to get them, recorded by a good player.